# Binyamin spelled with or without a second Yud

Tags: tanach, names, spelling-variants

In Tanach the name Binyomin appears 150 times as **בנימן**. It appears 16 times as **בנימין**. Why the difference?

The 16 times it appears with a Yud are as follows.

**בראשית לה:יח**

ויהי בצאת נפשה כי מתה ותקרא שמו בן אוני ואביו קרא לו בנימין

**בראשית מב:ד**

ואת בנימין אחי יוסף לא שלח יעקב את אחיו כי אמר פן יקראנו אסון

**בראשית מג:יד**

ואל שדי יתן לכם רחמים לפני האיש ושלח לכם את אחיכם אחר ואת בנימין ואני כאשר שכלתי שכלתי

**בראשית מג:טז**

וירא יוסף אתם את בנימין ויאמר לאשר על ביתו הבא את האנשים הביתה וטבח טבח והכן כי אתי יאכלו האנשים בצהרים

**בראשית מג:כט**

וישא עיניו וירא את בנימין אחיו בן אמו ויאמר הזה אחיכם הקטן אשר אמרתם אלי ויאמר אלהים יחנך בני

**בראשית מה:יב**

והנה עיניכם ראות ועיני אחי בנימין כי פי המדבר אליכם

**בראשית מט:כז**

בנימין זאב יטרף בבקר יאכל עד ולערב יחלק שלל

**יהושע כא:יז**

וממטה בנימין את גבעון ואת מגרשה את גבע ואת מגרשה

**שופטים ה:יד**

מני אפרים שרשם בעמלק אחריך בנימין בעממיך מני מכיר ירדו מחקקים ומזבולן משכים בשבט ספר

**שופטים י:ט**

ויעברו בני עמון את הירדן להלחם גם ביהודה ובבנימין ובבית אפרים ותצר לישראל מאד

**שמואל א יג:ב**

ויבחר לו שאול שלשת אלפים מישראל ויהיו עם שאול אלפים במכמש ובהר בית אל ואלף היו עם יונתן בגבעת בנימין ויתר העם שלח איש לאהליו

**שמואל ב ג:יט**

וידבר גם אבנר באזני בנימין וילך גם אבנר לדבר באזני דוד בחברון את כל אשר טוב בעיני ישראל ובעיני כל בית בנימן

**מלכים א יב:כג**

אמר אל רחבעם בן שלמה מלך יהודה ואל כל בית יהודה ובנימין ויתר העם לאמר

**ירמיהו לב:ח**

ויבא אלי חנמאל בן דדי כדבר יהוה אל חצר המטרה ויאמר אלי קנה נא את שדי אשר בענתות אשר בארץ בנימין כי לך משפט הירשה ולך הגאלה קנה לך ואדע כי דבר יהוה הוא

**הושע ה:ח**

תקעו שופר בגבעה חצצרה ברמה הריעו בית און אחריך בנימין

**נחמיה יא:לו**

ומן הלוים מחלקות יהודה לבנימין

Comment: Look at ירושלים, ירושלם or דוד, דויד

Comment: By Yerushalayim the Mefarshim explain the difference. I am looking for a reason by Binyamin.

Comment: I thought it was 17 times. Minchas Shai said 17: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2009/10/binyamin-with-three-yuds.html As to why, not a clue.

Comment: When I ran a search it shows 16 times, maybe it is a Kri/Ksiv

Comment: I know this will be a long list, but can you post the results of your search (maybe on an external page)? This way we can all have access to the same data-set and can look for patterns/_meforshim_...

Comment: Josh - Perhaps you can add in the 17th time - if you know what I left out?

Comment: so far, based on Tikkun Soferim, the 7 in Bereshit are comprehensive, as are the ones in Yehoshua and Nechemiah. But he then talks about where the remainder of the 10 (of the 17) are, and about errors therein... I cannot make out the name of the sefer he refers to that has the remaining ten. See here:
http://jnul.huji.ac.il/dl/books/djvu/1838482-1/index.djvu?djvuopts&thumbnails=yes&zoom=page&page=226

Comment: @joshwaxman Got it! It's [I Samuel 9:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90_%D7%98_%D7%90) Note the Keri uKetiv.

Comment: See this link for a discussion of whether to write it malei or chaser: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36130&st=&pgnum=151&hilite=

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert in Biblical Hebrew grammar, but it would seem based on the below commentary of the Torah Temimah that it has to do with the vowelization of the word throughout Tanach. The *mem* is generally vowellized with a *chirik*, and therefore does not need to be written with a *yud* to be pronounced properly, but in some cases it is not vowellized this way and therefore needs to be written with a *yud* to be pronounced properly.

Also it seems, based on the below and other commentaries, that in some places (eg. when Binyamin receives his name) it is crucial that is be spelled with a *yud* to express the meaning of the name (בן ימין - son of the right or strength, etc.).

> בכל התורה כתיב בנימן חסר והכא בנימין שלם כתיב [סוטה לו:]. דבפעם הראשון שזכר שם זה צריך לבאר סבת קריאת שם זה וכמו שפירש"י בן ימין בן הנולד בדרום, ולכן כתבו כאן מלא יו"ד, מה שאין כן בשאר המקומות כיון שהמ"ם נקרא בחיר"ק לא קפיד קרא למלא אותו ביו"ד, וכאשר כן הוא מדרך השמות שמתקצרים באותיות המשמשות... ועיין באבן העזר [קכט:ל] לענין כתיבת שם בנימין בגט, ומכאן סמך דצריך לכתוב חסר כמו בכל התורה
>
> [תורה תמימה]

Special thanks to Rabbi Zvi Ron (author of [Sefer Katan V'Gadol](http://www.rossipublications.com/main/author/rabbi-zvi-ron) a book on the big and small letters in Tanach) for the sources and guidance. [Full Disclosure: I published this book for him.]

Comment: If that link is gratuitous, please either remove it or let me know and I will remove it...I just felt like I should give the source of the info a shout-out and a way for him to benefit from helping me (and all of us) out.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11826/759