# Is there a book that explains the large and small letters in the Torah?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, aleph-bet-letters, size

I am seeking a book, in English, that lists and explains the reasons for the large and small letters in the Torah.  (A similar question on this topic did not specify English and did not elicit any references in English.)

Comment: Instead of asking for a book, why not ask your actual question?  (Answers might cite books.)  What do you want to know about the large and small letters?

Comment: Dup: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9510/501

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Given that there are quite a few of them, depending on what Yehuda is interested in learning, it may be more reasonable to ask for a resource than to ask for the information in that resource.

Comment: Yehuda W, see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: See [Yeivin's book, referred to](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57000/6603) in the other Q&A.