# Why is the מ in מוֹקְדָ֨ה small?

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, sefer-torah, tzav

In Parshat צו, Chapter 6, verse 2 the מ in מוֹקְדָ֨ה is small [according to Minchas Shai](https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Shai_on_Torah,_Leviticus.6.2.1). 
Why is the מ in מוֹקְדָ֨ה small?

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9510/3

Comment: [It's not small](http://www.nteiman.co.il/tort_amt/3/2.pdf)... (Compare with [Vayikra](http://www.nteiman.co.il/tort_amt/3/1.pdf) which has the small Alef.)

Comment: I’ve checked three different Chumashim, including a Tikkun, in addition to the one DoubleAA cites. The only one who says that this מ is small is [Minchas Shai](https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Shai_on_Torah,_Leviticus.6.2.1); nobody else seems to say that this should be a small מ.

Answer (score 2):

The [Oznaim Latorah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39723&st=&pgnum=85) explains that mokdah was the largest fire in the altar services. The small 'Mem' then came to teach us that everything great should demonstrate humility.

See several other reasons [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53295&st=&pgnum=136&hilite=).

Answer (score 2):

My Tikkun has the small mem as below.So Does my Bais Yehudah Chumash.
I once heard that Rav Menachem Mendel of Kotzk said that Moktah represents the fire we should have for Torah and Mitzvohs but keep it within yourself, in your heart, small. He continued , do your Mitzvohs in private and your sins in public. What did he mean? By doing sins in public, you become embarrassed and will cease to do them. By doing Mitzvohs in private, you avoid appearance of Haughtiness and Gaava at being religious.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md2kg.png): [image]