# Source of small/large letters in the torah

Tags: tanach, mesorah-tradition

Although there are many small and large letters throughout tanach, both the aleppo codex and the Leningrad codex have extremely few of them. Were they later introduced? The different miforshim, midrashim and halachik authorities seem to grant them significance.

Comment: I think *Sefer Hatoda'ah* ("Book of Our Heritage by Eliyah Kitov) addresses this. I think he says that these are Masoretic.

Comment: Interesting. If they're mesoretic why don't the mesorites list them?

Comment: Perhaps, there are different versions of which ones to use? I'm not overly familiar with the Allepo Codex to answer specifically what they do. I'll try to research this, further.

Comment: Have a look at this related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57000/5275