# Small Dalet in Mishlei (Proverbs) 28:17

Tags: words, aleph-bet-letters, mishlei

In [Mishlei (Proverbs) 28:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.28.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the letter dalet is small in the word "adam". Why is this?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57000/

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9510/759

Comment: @DoubleAA How? That talks about anything significant in the letters as a group; this talks about one particular instance. An answer to your proposition probably won’t address this at all.

Comment: His *daled* has become small so he will return to the *em*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The go-to sefer for this is [Sefer Katan v'Gadol](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/53295) by [R. Zvi Ron](http://www.rossipublications.com/main/author/rabbi-zvi-ron) (which I discovered via [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9154/4940)). Your case is on [page 258](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53295&st=&pgnum=268). The author brings four commentaries on this small dalet, as follows (in brief):

- Midrash R. Akiva — the dalet represents the gematria of 4 people "killed", who besides for the victim themselves are the victim's wife, their sons, and their daughters.
- R. Avraham Bick — the killer is reduced and diminished by the act.
- R. Nehemia Friedman — the dalet represents דם (blood), and the killer is diminished by the act (based on a drasha in [Sota 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.5a.20?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)).
- R. Pinchas Wolf — without the dalet (which again represents דם (blood)), the killer is no longer a person (אדם), and the remaining letters spell אם (if), so: if the sin of murder is on a person, then they are no longer considered a person (אדם). (I think that was what he's getting out of "אם", but it still works without that.)

See inside for (slightly) more details.

Comment: Im satisfied with this answer

Answer (score 0):

As a tentative answer, I would posit that if you read the word without the dalet - it becomes Eim - as in a mother.  This admonishment applies equally to both men and women, whether a woman has children or not.

Comment: Why by this particular admonishment is it necessary to say this?

Comment: Because it says *adam* the implication that this only applies to men and not women.

Comment: I think אדם as used in Tanach typically refers to humankind in general, as opposed to איש/אנוש or גבר which refer to men specifically. I could be wrong, but that seems to be the case.

Comment: Adam refers always to man in his pristine state.  In Bereishis it is used in contradistinction to Chava.

Comment: If you could cite that that would be great. According to your definition, what do you do with, I dunno, Vayikra 1:2? Can a woman not bring a Karban Olah? Or Bamidbar 19:16? Can a woman’s corpse not impart Tumas Meis?

Comment: I do think you’re onto something, so long as you can justify your premise.

Comment: You have to look at Chazal and see the deroshos applied in those instances.  There are other factors that lead one to read a pasuk. Since, in general, we can't make derashos, we look to chazal to help us.  Nonetheless, as I said, my answer was tentative, since I have not seen this anywhere and I have not seen a comment on it.

Comment: @DonielF I seem to remember that being stated in the context of the first _perek_ of _Chagiga_.

Comment: @WAF I've never learned Chagigah, so your guess is probably better than mine.

Answer (score -1):

According to the authoritative sefer on Masores [Mincas Shai](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.28.17?lang=bi&p2=Minchat_Shai_on_Proverbs.28.17.1&lang2=bi), the dalet is not small after all.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true, but anyway even if it was the question still stands according to the other opinions