# A Meta reason for the two spellings of Binyomin

Tags: blessing, tanach, mysticism-kabbalah, spelling-variants, drush

The word בנימן is spelt בנימין when he is born, this spelling is used around ten times. Otherwise, it is spelt with one י, why is this? I am **not** looking for a pshat answer. I am looking for a Drosh or kabbalistic that can explain the use of the extra letters and where they went.
This is not question [Binyamin spelled with or without a second Yud](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9070/binyamin-spelled-with-or-without-a-second-yud?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.0548) The answers there is Pshat as does the Minchas Shai quoted.

Thank you